# Hook into another application to watch memory usage

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

I just started writing an application that I would like to use to attach to any running process, and get notified when it allocates or deallocates memory.  I already created the interface so I can select from a list of running processes, but I don't really know how to hook into that process to get the information I'm looking for.

This is my first "real" C# application, so I'm still learning my way around.  I would like to use this application to test for memory leaks in other applications, it will just be a personal tool (and a learning experience) so it doesn't have to be perfect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [PerfMon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645516(VS.71).aspx) and what it has to offer?  You can implement custom counters, but it does show memory and GC  activity.  I've used this in the past to debug leaks.